# question related to paypal IPN (PHP)

Tags: php, paypal-subscriptions

I'm integrating paypal ipn in php. So If I enable auto return url in paypal. So there is need to pass following variables in paypal form?? here is variables.

```
    <input type="hidden" name="notify_url" value="http://site/ipn/" />
    <input type="hidden" name="return" value="http://site/ipn/" />
    <input type="hidden" name="rm" value="2">
```

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its not necessary. U may or maynot. but if you will pass `notify_url` and `return`, it will override the one you defined in paypal acoount.

hope this helps.

Comment: I have configured auto return url in paypal. Now I'm getting `INVALID` message. Can you help me ?

Comment: give a screenshot of your paypal setting.

Comment: INVALID means the IPN POST you're sending back to PayPal does not match the POST that was originally sent to you. This has nothing to do with PayPal Profile settings.